# AWS Quicksight - One graph/line for each ID and its values

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-quicksight

My data set in Quicksight looks something like this, with the following columns:

- `Person`
- `Account Balance`
- `Date`

Is there a way to plot the balance over time, for each person? I am looking for something like a line chart for each person.

I am not very keen on modifying my data set to contain a column for each person, e.g. create `Person1Balance`, `Person2Balance` as there are a lot of persons.

The filters in Quicksight does not seem very fitting either, since I would have to click through each person individually. Furthermore, I would not be able to see any number of values next to each other.

To me it seems as though Quicksight is built more for making aggregates and perform actions on the data. However, I am looking for a way to visualize and analyze my AWS data.

To get an idea of the visualization I am looking for I have attached is an image of a Grafana page containing Covid-19 statistics over time for some countries.
Thankful for any help, stay safe.

[image: Grafana example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to create similar line graph by setting:

- X axis as Date
- Value as Sum(Balance)
- Color as Person

and I get this nice graph.
[image: Quick Sight Analysis Line Chart]

Is this what you are looking for?

My datasource is a simple XLS with 3 columns as described in your question.

Comment: I have now tried this, works great. I did not think about the colors input being used like this, thanks a lot. Another thing, do you know if it is possible to scroll the dates? I have a lot of dates and they seem to be truncated to show only a few of the latest days.